# Updating to Windows 10, version 1903 still fails after required Intel RST update

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, intel-rst

Part way through the update to Windows 10 Version 1903 I get the error message

> If your device has an Intel® RST driver version between 15.1.0.1002 and 15.5.2.1053 installed, it cannot install the May 2019 Update.

I performed the update to Version: 17.5.1.1021 (Latest) Date: 7/10/2019 and rebooted several time but the same message appeared during the update, I also tried a version 16 update with the same error message. I've checked the installation logs which confirmed that I had the correct version and also checked in `Control Panel/Programs and Features` for the installed version.

I initiated the updated using `Settings/update&Security/Windows Update` and clicking the button

Comment: Try the older [15.9.6.1044](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/28656/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Intel-RST-User-Interface-and-Driver). Are you installing 1903 via Windows Update?

Comment: Was this an automatic Windows Update attempt to version 1903, or did you initiate the process yourself via the Media Creation Tool (or some other method)?

Comment: @Run5k I used the Windows Update feature

Comment: @harrymc I used the Windows Update feature; I tried the version you suggested but no difference, But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Understood, **but** did you initiate the process yourself (Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update and pressing appropriate button yourself), or was it an automatic push via Windows Update?

Comment: @Run5k I used `Settings/update&Security/Windows Update ` and clicked the button

Comment: Now if you don't mind me asking, why?  We are always glad to help, and it certainly sounds like you are quite computer literate.  However, the entire Windows 10 process that involves Feature Updates is rather elaborate, and if you haven't received version 1903 through an automatic update, it becomes a "proceed at your own risk" scenario. Personally, my entire home network is still on 1809 with a built-in 90-day delay before I would potentially receive 1903.  Everything works perfectly.  Is there some compelling new capability in version 1903 that makes it worth expediting?

Comment: Good question - I predate CP/M and DOS so why indeed. However, I tend to upgrade whenever it's available (a genetic defect perhaps)

Comment: And just for the record, my professional IT career predates DOS, also. But in my case, that wealth of experience has taught me to be *very* conservative regarding when to perform a full operating system upgrade.  Just something to consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the latest Intel RST driver seems not to work.  After clicking on the Refresh button the Installation Assistant still indicates that there is an old Intel RST driver installed.  Rebooting the Computer also does not help.

I was sure I have installed the latest driver so I stopped the Windows Update Service (Windows-Logo-Key + R; services.msc; Enter;).  While the service is stopped I have deleted the SoftwareDistribution-Folder (C:\windows\softwaredistribution).  Then I started the Windows Update service again.  Windows will download the 1903 Upgrade again and there won't be any errors anymore while installing the new OS.

Comment: Thanks. Have you succeeded with this?

Comment: Yes, by doing this, the problem was gone.

Comment: By removing `./SoftwareDistrubution` you force Windows to check for conflicts again.  The Intel RST was opened on July 25th, 2019, the suggested version of Intel RST, is 15.9.6.1044 by the way.  The resolution is very specific, you should not attempt to update until the Intel RST update is installed.  "Until an updated driver has been installed, we recommend you do not attempt to manually update using the Update now button or the Media Creation Tool." [source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-information/status-windows-10-1903#539msgdesc)

Comment: [Intel also does not recommend using the generic RST driver by the way if you have an OEM product (Dell, Lenovo, etc)](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/28656/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Intel-RST-User-Interface-and-Driver).

Comment: @Black thanks, that cleared the stalled updated nicely. I've decided to postpone the features upgrade for the moment. (+2 if I could)

Answer (score 1):

You have forced the installation before Microsoft decided to include your
computer in the upgrade process.
I would advice to wait for Microsoft to ask you to install it.

If you still want to force it:

Download the full version of the update from Microsoft at
[Download Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
as an ISO file.

Boot in Safe mode, then double-click the ISO and execute the setup program
to install Windows 10 version 1903.

Before starting, ensure you have good backups for your personal data.
If possible, take a backup image of the entire disk and ensure that you can restore it. Forcing the update this way is risky.

Comment: Thanks, I may try this, but not tonight, Also, I didn't force the installation, it was available via the standard update button.

Comment: This is still forcing it. You have just volunteered to test 1903 for Microsoft, which will be happy to know if you succeed (after enough successes 1903 will be released to your kind of setup). But if you fail and the computer becomes unusable, it's not Microsoft's problem any longer.

Comment: @PeterSmith, with all due respect that is simply a matter of terminology.  If you went out of your way to initiate the Windows 10 update process to version 1903, you essentially *did* force it.  As I said within my previous comment, I not only wait for the automatic installation process, I have configure the Windows 10 Pro machines on my home network with a delay of several months before they receive the latest Feature Update.  That system has served me quite well throughout the last four years since the OS was originally released, and a more conservative approach would probably help you, too.

Comment: @Run5k: I couldn't agree more.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers` and look for tyhe `iastor.sys` file. Rename the file to something else and reinstall 17.5 version.

I installed also 17.5 but the `iastor.sys` file was still from 2016.