# Can't update due to Intel RTS

Tags: windows-10

I got a notification by windows saying that it can't update to a newer version due to incompatibility to Intel Rapid Storage Technology (Intel RTS). It does offer a suggestion on the help page to update that software to a newer version.
I did that, but I got the same error. Next, I tried to uninstall it and got the same problem. And yes, I restarted the PC after each action.
Did anyone else encounter this problem or know how to fix it? Thanks
[image: Error image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating to Windows 10, version 1903 still fails after required Intel RST update](https://superuser.com/questions/1464803/updating-to-windows-10-version-1903-still-fails-after-required-intel-rst-update)

Answer (score 0):

If a Windows 10 user has Intel Rapid Storage Technology (Intel RST) driver versions between 15.1.0.1002 and 15.5.2.1053 installed, Windows 10 will not upgrade to version 1903.
To upgrade your driver, you should check your hardware manufacturer web site and see if a newer version is available for your computer model. This is the recommended solution by Intel when upgrading your Intel RST drivers as some manufacturers customize the driver for their particular hardware.
If a compatible version does not exist on the manufacturer's site, you can download the latest Intel RST drivers directly from Intel.

As previously stated, Microsoft recommends driver version 15.9.6.1044, but the latest one offered by Intel is currently version 17.5.1.1021 and includes includes functionality and security updates.

Comment: updating does not resolve the windows update issue

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the name of the old driver (iastora.sys).
You find this driver in the   c:\windows\system32\drivers    directory. Change the name to iastora_old.sys,  restart the system and update windows. Windows seems to keep using or regestering the old driver.